# Numpy fails to serve as a dependency for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was trying to use pandas (installed the binaries and dependencies using conda, then using pip, then built then using no-binaries option); still getting error.

Numpy is available (1.11.2).
I understand some interface is not provided by numpy anymore.
Python version I am using is 2.7.11.
List of packages installed are bellow.

Error message:

> C:.....Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py:14: Warning:
>   Numpy built with MINGW-W64 on Windows 64 bits is experimental, and
>   only available for testing. You are advised not to use it for
>   production.
>
> CRASHES ARE TO BE EXPECTED - PLEASE REPORT THEM TO NUMPY DEVELOPERS
>   from . import multiarray Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "io.py", line 2, in  from data import support File
>   "....\support.py", line 3, in  import pandas File
>   "....Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 18, in
>    raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies
>   {0}".format(missing_dependencies)) ImportError: Missing required
>   dependencies ['numpy']

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not building from source on Windows unless you really know what you're doing.

Also, don't mix conda and pip for numpy; numpy is treated specially in conda and really should work out of the box. If you get an error on import pandas there's likely something wrong with your PATH or PYTHONPATH.

I suggest that you just create an empty conda env, and install only pandas in it. That will pull in numpy. If that somehow does not work, let's see if we can help you debug that.